# silverlight...hyperlinkbutton to file using relative path

Tags: silverlight, download

I am trying to use a hyperlinkbutton in silverlight to enable the user to download a word document.  I don't care if a file save as box appears or if the word doc opens in a new browser.  I get the error "cannot navigate to locations relative to a page."  I've seen it posted that you can do this with the absolute path (www.domain.com/filename.doc) but there's got to be a way to make this relative (/docs/filename.doc).  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HyperlinkButton only works with absolute URLS, so you should fixup your URLs at runtime:

```
uriCurrent = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri;
string current = uriCurrent.OriginalString;
int iLastSlash = current.LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
current = current.Remove(iLastSlash, current.Length - iLastSlash);
```

from [Silverlight.net forums](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/12073.aspx).

Comment: Okay...that seems like it mostly solves my problem...is there a way to make that work with Cassini?

Comment: Nevermind it works with Cassini too...I just had to append "ClientBin" in the path

Answer (score 13):

Slightly easier:

```
Uri myAbsoluteUri = new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, myRelativePath);
```