# Silverlight Cache Control: Using revision number in url for XAP causes HyperLink to crash SL App!

Tags: silverlight, caching, silverlight-2.0

To make sure all our customers receive the latest Silverlight App, we are placing the new revision number on the url for XAP file as follows:

```
<param name="source" value="/ClientBin/ShoeboxViewer.xap?v=5" />
```

Problem is when we do this, all HyperLink controls (in the Silverlight App) that use relative URLs, throw an internal error when clicked. Here's the stack trace:

> Unhandled Error in Silverlight 2 Application Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: baseUri
>    at System.Uri..ctor(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri)
>    at System.Windows.Controls.HyperlinkButton.GetAbsoluteUri()
>    at System.Windows.Controls.HyperlinkButton.Navigate()
>    at System.Windows.Controls.HyperlinkButton.OnClick()
>    at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
>    at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
>    at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)

If I remove the querystring, it works fine.

Can anyone help?

Cheers,
Ash.

Comment: Were you having a problem with your users not getting the latest revision?

Comment: If so, were these users on Macs?  The empty IFrame after the object tag deals with this issue.

Comment: The latest version issue is a problem on pc's too. It's basically because the browser uses the cached version instead of the new version. By changing the param, it tricks it into thinking it's a different uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob is right - you might also want to look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405812/silverlight-hyperlinkbutton-to-file-using-relative-path/407626#407626) to fixup relative URLs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually that HyperlinkButtons can't use relative urls. I ran into this just the other day.  It's a hack, but I got it to work by adding a click handler to the HyperlinkButton and then calling HtmlPage.Navigate, passing in a uri marked as relative